# "On the weekend" or "during the weekend"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Which is correct?

> I will see her **on** the weekend.
>
> I will see her **during** the weekend.

Comment: I've also heard a lot of people say "in the weekend"

Comment: Or what about "at" the end. For instance, when you use "end," you can say "in the (week)end," as Jason said above, or, "at the (week)end." Just a thought

Comment: In my opinion, "in the weekend" is a colloquialism that one would do well to avoid, especially in written contexts of any kind.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Neither. The answer is “this weekend”, as in “I will see her **this weekend**.” Depending on which weekend you mean, you could also say “next weekend”, which is the weekend following “this weekend”.

“On the weekend” is sometimes used, but sounds odd to me. “During the weekend” would only be applicable if you were clarifying that you meant not before or after, but **during** the weekend.

Comment: -1: Per the answers & comments re [what day is next tuesday?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3841/) it's clear *this* and *next* are to some extent ambiguous, so by proscribing all prepositions you don't somehow magically resolve all usage issues. Anyway, although I've no authoritative source to back me up, I suspect most speakers *like* to include a preposition. There's no reason they shouldn't do this, just because some other people use a *different* one.

Answer (score 8):

The best choice for your construction would be **over the weekend**.

Comment: Upvoted with misgivings. Per my answer, **over** is most common in the US, and second most common in the UK, so it's ideal for Americans, but something of a compromise for Brits. Also, I don't remember taking against Neil Young for [Out On The Weekend](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TXAXHWnfRQo), so it's not obvious to me anyone should feel under any pressure to use anything other than whatever the people around them use (unless they're surrounded by people who say *in the weekend*, in which case they should definitely  take your advice! :)

Answer (score 6):

It's pointless trying to make a case for any difference in meaning between any of these prepositions. The main area where usage varies is that [Americans favour "on the weekend"](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=at%20the%20weekend,on%20the%20weekend&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=5&smoothing=3)

[image]

whereas [Britons favour "at the weekend"](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=at%20the%20weekend,on%20the%20weekend&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=6&smoothing=3)

[image]

Both nations also use ***over*** the weekend (for Americans, this is actually the most common form; for Brits, it's a close second). But for Brits, ***during*** the weekend is the least favoured of these top four prepositions (it's second-to-bottom for Americans, who **really** don't like ***at*** the weekend). And I'm pleased to report that ***in*** the weekend just isn't in the running according to NGrams!

Most speakers will be quite safe with *this/next weekend*, because most people in any particular linguistic community will have a common understanding of what these terms mean, but it's worth knowing that [others may think differently](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/29104/this-weekend-vs-next-weekend), particularly when you're online and interacting with people who don't necessarily share your local idiomatic usage.

Answer (score 5):

I would  suggest **at the weekend** as normal English usage.

Comment: There must be a regional difference at play here: to me, *at the weekend* sounds awkward at best.

Comment: You're both right. The Brits & Irish say "at" and North Americans "on". And "late(r) **in** the weekend" is common on both sides I believe.

Comment: -1: Per my usage charts, you're very likely **British**. If you'd said *"normal British usage"* I'd have either upvoted, or at least not downvoted. But given Americans overwhelmingly use **on**, and given there are far more of them than there are Brits, this answer is simply wrong.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - so you give out downvotes for someone using the word "English" to mean "characteristic of England"?  Interesting!

Comment: @David Wallace: I don't see I have much choice sometimes on a site called *English Language & Usage*, where clearly the word means *Anglophone*. If Constantine did indeed mean *of England* it's appallingly ambiguous usage in this context. Either the wording of the answer is misleading, or it's incorrect anyway; whichever way I look at it, it's definitely downvotable in my eyes.

Answer (score 3):

*On the weekend* is the normal usage. You can use *during the weekend* if your meaning specifically involves periods of time rather than just sometime "on the weekend."