# A week on monday?

Tags: phrase-meaning

Someone asked "When is your job interview?"
And the other answered "A week on Monday."

What does it mean by using "a week" before Monday?
Does it mean Monday next week?

Comment: Mentioned at ['Is “this Monday” or “next Monday” the correct way to refer to the very next Monday in the future?'](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10431/is-this-monday-or-next-monday-the-correct-way-to-refer-to-the-very-next-mond/10434#10434)

Comment: 'Monday next week' would surely be "next Monday" or even "on Monday".

Comment: In the UK we (some of us, at least) say things like [*See you Monday week*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22you+monday+week%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), but I don't think I've ever heard that construction in an American accent.

Comment: This and next mean very different things here.  Said on Monday, next Monday is a week away.  Said on Tuesday, next Monday is two weeks away.  This Monday is either today or a week away.  You'll miss a lot of parties in Minnesota.

Answer (score 2):

"a week on Monday" means "on Monday, a week", i.e.

"When is your job interview?"

"On Monday, the job interview will be in a week's time."

or

"When Monday comes, the job interview will be in a week."

Answer (score 1):

It means that the interview will take place one week from next Monday.  This is unambiguous if said when it's not Monday.

Comment: Whoa!  There are next Mondays and this Mondays.  Lets say it's Tuesday today making this Monday 6 days away.  You just said that the interview will occur almost 3 weeks from today.  This Monday is in 6 days; next Monday is in 13 and then add a week.  Are your sure?  (Yankee use of this and next with dates.)

Comment: It doesn't work if today is Monday.