# Difference between "Coming weekend" and "This weekend"?

Tags: meaning, differences

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Next Friday” vs. “This Friday”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/36419/next-friday-vs-this-friday)

Consider the following statements:

> I'll meet you coming wednesday
>   I'll meet you next wednesday
>   I'll meet you this wednesday

All the pages I've seen till now, like [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/29104/this-weekend-vs-next-weekend) one use *next* and *this*, but I don't see anywhere what the *coming* means.

As I know it, *coming wednesday* means the current week's wednesday and *next wednesday* is for the next week's wednesday.

Comment: I've never seen "coming" without it being "this coming Wednesday"

Comment: Shrinath - This is an "Indian English usage" in my experience. Is that where you've heard it too?

Comment: @simchona : Agreed

Comment: @Josek : yeah :)

Comment: @Shrinath: You're welcome. I hope the answers to that question helps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, the sentence would be "I'll meet you this coming Wednesday", not "I'll meet you coming Wednesday." The latter sentence is not grammatically correct.

You can think of it as referring to the Wednesday that is **coming up ahead**. So, "I'll meet you this coming Wednesday" has the same meaning that "I'll meet you this Wednesday" does.

Comment: The absence of "this" was really the issue then :)

Answer (score 0):

*This weekend* can be interpreted to mean either the nearest weekend in the future or the nearest weekend in the past. The context usually clarifies the meaning, but *coming* or *past* can be added to help:

> *The meeting was this weekend.*
>
> *The meeting was this coming weekend.*
>
> *The meeting was this past weekend.*

In the first case, I'd think that means that the meeting happened over the weekend that just passed, but it might instead mean that the meeting was scheduled to happen a few days in the future, but was cancelled or moved. In the second and third cases, there's no room for misunderstanding; in the second case the meeting must have been moved, and in the third case the meeting has already happened.

I've never seen *coming weekend* without the *this*, but it may be some regional variation where the *this* was dropped.