# collocation with BUS STOP

Tags: word-choice

Is it possible to say "I have to take 5 stops by/on bus to get to my school"?  meaning: my school is 5 stops away from my home, I get there by bus.

Comment: Related: [Counting stops without ambiguity](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/114313/).

Comment: "My school is five bus stops away." Just like you said, really, and that's exactly how you say it. Don't say that you take stops instead. You don't take the stops, you take the bus. Nobody goes to school by stops in English, just like никто не добирается до школы на пяти автобусных остановках in Russian or whatever the Ukrainian equivalent is, I'm nof fluent in Ukrainian.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, either are possible. 
One would usually say, for instance, '*I went **by** bus*', but in some situations (e. g., if you want to emphasize the fact that you *went* by bus, as opposed to walking or some other form of transportation), it might be appropriate to say '*I went **on** **a** bus*' (note that the use of the indefinite article is *essential*).

Comment: In London, where there are extensive underground ("Tube") and above-ground railways, people also use the word "stop" to mean "station", and will say e.g. "my journey is three stops by Tube (or train)".

Comment: Thanks. But what about the word STOP usage here ? Is "take 5 stops to get there" ok ?

Comment: I would say "I have to pass 5 bus stops on the way to school", since the stops are not equally distant from each-other.

Comment: OK, but you do say " live 5 stops away from school", don't you?

Comment: @LiliyaRyaboshapko Yes, "I live 5 stops away" sounds fine. The problem is with "I have to take 5 stops." First of all, it's not common phrasing. But, secondly, without the context of how long the bus ride is, it would more commonly be taken to mean that *you* have to take 5 stops rather than that the bus has to. In other words, that you have to get on and off the bus 5 times in order to run errands (or something). You might instead say something similar to, "I have to travel by/on a bus that makes 5 stops to get to my school."