# Different usage between 'A First Generation' and 'A Second Generation' American

Tags: meaning

Here is what I have always thought: My grandparents, on both sides, immigrated from other countries. (Not sure of their citizenship status, or even if that matters.) They were the first 'generators' of future Americans, my parents, were second generation, so that makes me 3rd generation. Is this correct?

Comment: It appears to me that your grandparents were, on arrival, say, Danish; your parents - born in America - were first generation American, and you are second generation American.

Comment: "According to US Census Bureau, the first generation of immigrants is composed of individuals who are foreign-born." That appears to confirm my assumptions.

Comment: So it might matter if my grandparents were citizens or even established residency, (which they did by getting US mail), still not sure.

Comment: You might want to ask on the genealogy site. I think they’d agree with @Greybeard. So the terms are used with different meanings.

Comment: "Generators"???

Comment: @SFSkol *"According to US Census Bureau, the first generation of immigrants is composed of individuals who are foreign-born."* Note that there is a difference between "first generation **immigrants**" and "first generation **Americans**".

Comment: In his answer to the question about [counting stops without ambiguity](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/114313), @Mitch observed that '"normal" people count starting from 1[, but] some technically minded people start counting from 0'. That may arguably have some relevance here.

Comment: @jsw29 When I'm reading on StackExchange, I start by reading the 0th answer to a question.

Answer (score 13):

If you believe the government, first generation Americans are foreign born:

> The first generation refers to those who are foreign born. The second generation refers to those with at least one foreign-born parent. The third-and-higher generation includes those with two U.S. native parents. — [US Census Bureau](https://www.census.gov/topics/population/foreign-born/about/faq.html)

If you look at usage, then it's mixed. [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/first-generation) neatly shows this by listing both:

> 1. born in the U.S. —used of an American of immigrant parentage
> 2. FOREIGN-BORN —used of a naturalized American

First generation Americans are the first generation to be "American" and that's what makes it unclear. Can an immigrant become American? It depends who you ask.

With other words, there is no question: a first generation college graduate has parents who didn't graduate college, for example.

See also [ThoughtCo](https://www.thoughtco.com/first-generation-immigrant-defined-1951570).

Comment: "Can an immigrant become American?" Immigrants can become citizens. So it doesn't really depend on who you ask.

Comment: @DJClayworth There are plenty of naturalized and native-born citizens who are treated as foreigners because of their appearance or accents. So no, it isn't that simple.

Comment: There is a word for people who treat American citizens as 'foreigners" because of their appearance and accents.

Comment: It not obvious whether the quoted definition should be regarded as only a stipulative definition that applies to the Bureau's documents, but has no force outside them, or as something that may illuminate how these terms are used generally.

Comment: I'm an immigrant who eventually naturalized and became an American citizen.  our daughter accompanied us across the border as a toddler when we moved and auto-magically got citizenship (via the Child Citizenship Act of 2000) when we naturalized.  I'm from Canada.  I'm White and speak with a neutral North American accent.  No one believes we are immigrants - I've had people seem to want to pick a fight because they didn't believe my immigrant status (the opposite of what @DJClayworth speaks, but basically the same).  I've given up trying to answer if I'm "1st generation" (or she is)

Answer (score 7):

The usual phrase is *First-Generation **Immigrant***.
"American" doesn't mean anything in that context.

Immigrants who come from another country are First-Generation immigrants.
Their children are Second-Generation immigrants (*Nisei* in Japanese).
**Their** children are Third-Generation immigrants (*Sansei*).
And so it goes.

Becoming an American means becoming a citizen, which involves filling out forms,
taking tests, and fulfilling other requirements. Immigrants of any generation can become citizens.

Comment: In what context would "nth-generation immigrant" be standard? I've only heard "nth-generation American" in everyday usage (I have in-laws who are naturalized citizens). Referring to someone born in the US as an "immigrant" would be unusual and possibly offensive (I expect that would be different in places without jus soli citizenship).

Comment: It might be if you weren't a statistician.

Comment: This may be the technical terminology of a particular field, but I doubt that it is 'usual' among ordinary English speakers to use the word *immigrant* for somebody who has never immigrated from anywhere. An immigrant is, by the most standard definition, somebody who immigrates, so the phrase *nth-generation immigrant* makes no sense, outside some field in which it is stipulatively defined as a technical term. Also, people born in the United States cannot become the citizens of the United States; they are citizens by birth.

Comment: But are they capitalized? [ha ha]

Answer (score 1):

I am a first generation immigrant to the US because I was born in the UK.
My children are second generation immigrants.
The number refers to the number of levels (minus 1) to get to the most recent immigrant ancestor

Answer (score 0):

Taken at face value, apart from any context, the phrases of the form ***n**th-generation American* (or *Canadian*, *Australian*, etc.) are ambiguous, because the word *American* is itself ambiguous. It can mean:

**(1)** somebody who has lived a significant part of his or her life in the United States, and whose life has been significantly coloured by American culture, **or**

**(2)** somebody who was born in the United States, **or**

**(3)** somebody who is a citizen of the United States.

If by *American* one means (1), then the people who immigrated into the United States are themselves first-generation Americans, their children are second-generation Americans, and so forth. If by *American* one means (2), then the children of the immigrants are the first generation. If by *American* one means (3), then the counting depends on whether the relevant immigrants were naturalised.

Now, I expect that, outside specialised contexts, in casual day-to-day conversations, most people mean by *American* something like (1), because in ordinary everyday interaction with people, their places of residence and cultural affiliations are more salient than the places of their birth or their citizenship. From that it follows that, in the absence of contextual clues that would indicate otherwise, it is most reasonable to interpret *first-generation Americans* as standing for those who immigrated into the United States (regardless of whether they are naturalised), *second-generation Americans* for their children, and so forth.

However, because terms of the form ***n**th-generation American* are not entirely unambiguous, it may be wise to avoid them and convey such information by some entirely different language, such as 'Her parents immigrated from . . . and she was born here' or 'It was his grandparents that immigrated into this country from . . .'.

Incidentally, eschewing the ***n**th-generation* terminology also avoids the awkwardness that arises when one tries to apply it to those who immigrated with their parents (which may be compounded by their having siblings born after the move).

Of course, if one is in some specialised context, in which such terms are explicitly, stupulatively defined, then one should use them in accordance with these field-specific definitions.

The question asked only about the phrases of the form ***n**th-generation American* and not about the phrases of the form ***n**th-generation immigrant*, but the latter have been introduced into the discussion in the other contributions to this page, so something need to be said about them as well. Wikipedia has an article on [Immigrant Generations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immigrant_generations) which acknowledges that terms of the form ***n**th-generation immigrant* are used in sociology and that

> the categorization of immigrants into generations helps sociologists and demographers track how the children and subsequent generations of immigrant forebears compare to sections of the population that do not have immigrant background,

but also points out that

> the term *second-generation immigrant* attracts criticism due to it being an oxymoron. Namely, critics say, a "second-generation immigrant" is not an immigrant, since being "second-generation" means that the person is born in the country and the person's parents are the immigrants in question.

If one wanted to excuse the sociologists' use of these terms, which is from a lay person's viewpoint bizarre, one could argue that it may be a result of their taking communities as their primary objects of investigation, rather than individuals as individuals. It is not unnatural to use the terms such as *immigrant community* or *immigrant family* for communities/families whose character is shaped by immigrants, even if some of their younger members are not themselves immigrants. On this reasoning *second-generation immigrant*, which is absurd when taken literally, can be regarded as a shortening of *second-generation member of the immigrant community*.

Comment: I'm sorry but the thing about you can be American if you lived a significant part of your life in the US is just wrong. Having a nationality is a legal status. Cultural identity is another. That would then be true of any nationality.

Comment: @Lambie, you are using *American* to mean (3), which is perfectly apt is some contexts. When people refer to their acquaintances as Americans, Canadians, Germans, etc., in casual conversations, however, they do so without having seen, or having any interest in seeing, their passports, birth certificates and suchlike.