# Definite article and ranking adjectives

Tags: grammar, articles, definite-articles

I'm trying to systematize the use of 'the' with ranking adjectives like 'next', 'following', 'third', etc.

What I know is usually ranking adjective is used with **the**:

> I will pay **the next time** we have dinner.
>
> Don't forget **the following rule**.

But at the same time:

> Maybe I can do that **next summer**.
>
> We could get together **next Monday**.
>
> I think I did well on the test, but I won't know until **next week**.

So, as I understand it:

> Next + days of week, seasons and the noun phrase next week are just
> some exceptions I have encountered so far.

I want to know when to put **the** and when not to. If I'm oversimplifying the matter or completely mistaken about it, that's all right. I just need to figure it out.

Comment: Sounds like you've got the basic idea.  There are always exceptions.  And exceptions to the exceptions.

Comment: Btw, I would also add *next year* to those exceptions.

Comment: Don't forget **the week after next**.

Comment: Related: [“Planning for next year” vs. “planning for the next year”](//english.stackexchange.com/q/92354/26083) and [“the next day” or “next day”](//english.stackexchange.com/q/167147/26083). … … … … I believe “I will pay **next time** we have dinner.” could go either way. … … … … As Hot Licks says, there are always exceptions. For example, the bank teller says, “Next person in line, come forward.” (but it could also be “The next person in line can come forward.”)

Comment: Also, the discussions here have sidestepped the related can of worms: [Which day does “next Tuesday” refer to?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/3841/26083), [How did “next day” come to mean “day of next week”?](//english.stackexchange.com/q/40869/26083), [Meaning of “last/this/next Monday”](//english.stackexchange.com/q/57228/26083), [“Next Friday” vs. “This Friday”](//english.stackexchange.com/q/36419/26083), and more.

Answer (score 3):

The rule for **next Monday** and **the next Monday** is simple.

**Next Monday** refers to the Monday that comes after the present one [(US)](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/essential-american-english/next_1)/ the Monday that comes after the present one or previous one [(British)](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/next#next__13)

If you refer to a different Monday in the future or in the past, you have to use 'the'.

A Monday in the past: "When we arrived, we were told that the airport would open only the next Monday."

A Monday in the future that's later then next Monday: "We will be arriving there in two week's time and the crew will follow the next Monday."

Likewise for the next year, the next season, etc...

References:

> When we talk about days of the week, weeks, months, years, seasons or
>   public holidays in the future in relation to now, we use *next* without
>   *the* and without a preposition:
>
> - *I have an appointment with the dentist **next** Wednesday morning.*
>     (Not: … the next Wednesday morning).
> - *Are you working **next** week?*
>     (Not: Are you working on next week?)
> - ***Next*** year will be our fortieth wedding anniversary.
> - *We’re going to plant some new flowers **next** spring.*
>
> To refer to the future, we can use *the next few hours*,
>   *the next two days*, *the next six months*, etc.:
>
> - *I’ll finish the work in **the next few days**. You can pay me then.*
> - *We’ll be home for **the next three weeks**,
>     then we’re going away to France for two weeks.*
>
> When we talk about times in the past or future not related to now, we
>   normally use *the*. However, in informal situations, we can omit *the*
>   when we talk about the past:
>
> - ***The next day*** we travelled to the ancient city of Qom.
> - *We’re going to spend the first night in Oslo,
>     then **the next day** we’ll fly to Narvik.*
> - *Two policemen grabbed me.
>     **Next minute**, I was arrested and thrown into a van.*
>
> Page 319, *English Grammar Today*, Cambridge University Press, ©2011  
>   [[online link]](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/next)

See also section 4.4.6 (c), Page 281- *Longman Grammar of Spoken and Written English*, ©1999. The article is too long to quote here.

Comment: Interesting. Sounds plausible. Do you have a source for this guidance? We prefer answers that identify references.

Comment: @Scott: I found it for you.

Comment: See section 4.4.6 (c), Page 281- _Longman Grammar of Spoken and Written English_, (C)1999. The article is too long to quote here.

Comment: @ThanOo It's best to put references and additions to your answer in the answer itself by editing it. Comments can dissappear and should not be used for anything that is or supports an answer.

Comment: (1) Thanks for identifying your source.  (2) It doesn’t entirely support your answer.  You say, “**Next Monday** refers to the soonest Monday that comes after today.”  Well, that might be true for “Monday”, but that’s a special case, so it’s a bad example.  If today is Wednesday, October 12, then “next Friday” is Friday, October 21 (the Friday *of **next week***) — as stated [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/3841/26083#3844), [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/40869/26083), and [here](/q/36419/26083) — and not Friday, October 14 (the soonest Friday that comes after today).

Comment: I noticed that usage difference between American and British English the first time I read this question. It was unwise of me to have ignored it, knowing, unlike me, most of the contributors speak American English. I have updated my answer accordingly. Unfortunately the ambiguity and confusion will definitely persist with days of the week.

Answer (score 2):

Those ranking adjectives are definite ordinal determiners.  'The' is itself an ordinal determiner with offset=0 ('next'=+1, ...).  Despite the redundancy, we
still say things like 'I'll take the next cab.' It is wise to keep 'the' for definiteness, so we aren't tripped up by proper nouns like 'Next Wave Cab Co.'
Time periods such as 'Monday' are already proper nouns, so we can drop 'the' unless there are multiples to choose from (such as 'the Monday after the test').  Time periods are often used as adverbials.  They are so common that we often omit the comma that marks them as adverbial. PS: 'until next week' can be expanded to ', until [it{now} is] [at] [the] next week'.