# What does 'next Monday' mean?

Tags: ambiguity, this-next

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which day does “next Tuesday” refer to?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3841/which-day-does-next-tuesday-refer-to)
>   [Meaning of “last/this/next Monday”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/57228/meaning-of-last-this-next-monday)

> Scenario: You get a phone call on Wednesday, saying "you have to report
>   to X next Monday".

When do you report? The upcoming  Monday or the Monday after that?

Other questions on here have no solid answer.

Comment: Questions like this are answered and discussed in Fillmore's _[Deixis Lectures](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Deixis.html)_ (which are not mentioned, let alone linked, in the "possible duplicate" answer above, btw); specifically, [Lecture 3 "Time"](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/3-Time.pdf).

Comment: OK, I see the second link above now references Fillmore. Thank you. In the sweet bye-and-bye, when all the duplicates have been merged, tagged, and indexed properly, no doubt this will be helpful.