# Are both of these equally correct?

Tags: expression-choice

> An event, announced to be held on January 12th **this year**, was canceled
> due to public objections.
>
> An event, announced to be held on **last** January 12th, was canceled due
> to public objections.

Are both of these correct? Which one is more idiomatic? Another other way better to say that?

Comment: Both are clear in meaning and there is no “correct” version. That woikd be a matter of opinion only.

Comment: When were these statements made? Before January 12th or after?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Meaning of "last/this/next Monday"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/57228/meaning-of-last-this-next-monday) (for 'last January 12th'; 'January 12th this year' is of course well-defined).

Comment: @Jim After January 12th.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are correct, except in the second sentence  for a "12th" which is consistently "12".

[on last January](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22on%20last%20january%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en)

[on last April 1](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22on%20last%20april%201%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en)

[on last April 5](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22on%20last%20april%205%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en)

[on April 15](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22on%20last%20april%2015%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en)

[on last August 1](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22on%20last%20august%201%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en)

Also, in the first one "st", "nd" and "th" can be omitted.

[image]

Both are fully idiomatic, but it is not certain which is used more.

[image]

There is the alternative "*on the 12th of January last*", which, personally, bar for the greater length, I find just as good, but it is not used much any more, neither in BrE nor in AmE.