# Are 'next Friday' and 'this Friday' the same?

Tags: terminology, this-next

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which day does “next Tuesday” refer to?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3841/which-day-does-next-tuesday-refer-to)

To me, they both mean the same thing, the upcoming Friday, but I know people who say that 'next Friday' is the one after this Friday.

Is there any canonical view or common usage that can help clarify?

Comment: This whateverday is the whateverday from this week.  Next whateverday is the whateverday from next week.  Last whateverday is the whateverday from last week.  So long as you know what week you are in, you are fine.

Comment: Depends on the speaker. _This Friday_ is the Friday of this week, and _next Friday_ is the Friday of next week, not this week: it can be 13 days away. That, in my experience, is how many but not all native English-speakers use those two phrases, so I find that it's always necessary to ask what they mean.

Comment: Also may differ between US and UK.