# "This month" vs. "next month"

Tags: word-choice, this-next, deixis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which day does “next Tuesday” refer to?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3841/which-day-does-next-tuesday-refer-to)

If it is November, how do you refer to the upcoming July? Is it "this July" or "next July"?

Answer (score 3):

**This July** would imply the current year's July, regardless of whether it is in the past or future.

This ***coming*** July always indicates future, regardless of year.

Comment: @WillHunting, aargh! I knew that was coming!  Personally, I'd avoid that phrase due to its ambiguity. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Use of a [deictic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deixis) word like *this* (or *that*, or *next*, or *last*, etc.) with a time word like *July* or *month* marks a case of Temporal Deixis, a phenomenon that was definitively explained in Fillmore's 1971 [Santa Cruz Deixis Lectures](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Deixis.html).

Temporal deixis is treated in Lecture 4, *[Deixis I](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/4-Deixis-I.pdf)*, but that lecture contains a number of references to the three previous lectures (1, *"[May We Come In?](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/1-MayWeComeIn.pdf)"*; 2, *[Space](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/2-Space.pdf)*; and 3, *[Time](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/3-Time.pdf)*), so reading them in numeric order may be helpful.