# What do you call a word whose meaning changes according to when or where it is said?

Tags: terminology, deixis

I remember learning a specific name for words whose meaning depends on the time or location of their use, but as this was when I was in middle school (about 10 years ago), I can't remember what exactly that name is.

My teacher gave the example of *here*, which means "Chicago" when spoken by a person in Chicago, "Egypt" when spoken by a person in Egypt, etc. There are also time equivalents, such as *now* (the meaning of which is constantly changing), *soon*, *today*, *yesterday*, and *tomorrow.* As I'm writing this, *today* refers to April 14, 2015; *yesterday* refers to April 13, 2015; and *tomorrow* refers to April 15, 2015. However, on any other date, those words would mean different things.

I thought that these might be called **relative words** since their meaning is relative to the circumstances of their use, but when I searched for that phrase, it seems to have a [much broader meaning](http://www.answers.com/Q/What_is_an_example_of_a_relative_word), referring to any "word that does not have an exact definition." This could be words like *big*, *small*, *short*, *tall*, *dumb*, *smart*, etc.—You are tall compared to a mouse, but you are not tall compared to an elephant.

I remember that the word I learned was specific to words whose meaning altered according to place and time, so I'm looking for something more specific than *relative word.*

Comment: This random Yahoo! answer gives the answer ["Temporal"](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20120218094911AAjTfjn). I'm not sure if that's the word, but seems to fit the examples you've given.

Comment: They're **deictic**. See ['This month' vs 'next month'](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/92266/this-month-vs-next-month/92275#92275).

Comment: @Edwin: I can usually remember what *deitic* means when I see it in context, but I couldn't reliably pull it out of the hat if asked to "name that word". I think this is a good question - well presented, with what I would call a *definitive* answer. And I'm not sure it would be entirely kosher to closevote against John's answer in your link, since *deitic* only arises incidentally, and that question is closed anyway. So I think you should post an *answer* we can upvote instead of the comment.

Comment: I feel, based on all answers & comments, "Relative" is too restricted, "Contextual" is too wide, while "Deictic" is the exact fit. The noun form is "Deixis". So @EdwinAshworth should add his comment as an answer.

Comment: I've had time to check for duplicates now.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The more specific term is **deixis** (the phenomenon) and such words are **deictic**.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deixis):

> In linguistics, deixis refers to words and phrases that cannot be
>   fully understood without additional contextual information. Words are
>   deictic if their semantic meaning is fixed but their denotational
>   meaning varies depending on time and/or place. Words or phrases that
>   require contextual information to convey any meaning – for example,
>   English pronouns – are deictic....

This has been mentioned here before, and there have been discussions about problems in labelling say distal locative situations ("Is this Jill speaking?"). And John Lawler's answer to ['What part of speech does “here” have in “I am here”?'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/111058/what-part-of-speech-does-here-have-in-i-am-here/111063#111063) is priceless and worth repeating:

> ... you're not playing with a full deck, if you take your definitions
>   of "part of speech" from English books. They're hopeless; pay no
>   attention to them.
>
> *Here* is a proximal deictic locative predicate in the sentence
>   - I am here.
>
> It does not modify the verb am.
>
> It does not modify anything, in fact.
>
> (Be) here is the Predicate in the sentence.
>
> The logical form is
>   - HERE (I)
>
> The am is indeed an auxiliary verb, meaning, like the Spanish
>   auxiliary estar, 'be located (at)'.
>
> Executive Summary: Calling something an "adverb" is a confession of
>   ignorance.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it!

Comment: I have this guilty feeling that John didn't get this many upvotes for the answer I've merely quoted. But then imitation ...

Comment: Keep in mind you're being upvoted for the quote _and_ your description of deixis.

Answer (score 3):

I would call them *contextual*.