# How do you say the coming week in the weekend?

Tags: meaning, terminology

Now it is on Saturday(25 May 2013), how do you say the coming week(the week from 27th-)?
Next week or is it already this week? Is there any other ways to say the coming week?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3841/which-day-does-next-tuesday-refer-to

Answer (score 1):

In the UK, we might say ***this coming week***.

I may be wrong, but I don't think many British people would say *this week* in the situation described.

Comment: They absolutely would, in some contexts.  Consider "Have we got any bookings this week?".  Plenty of people would say that, and take that, to mean the coming week.  The context of the question tells us that the speaker is talking about the future.  I agree that "this coming week" helps prevent ambiguity though.

Answer (score 0):

It's *this week,* which can be determined purely pragmatically.

A sentence which expresses a future act and "this week" must refer to the immediately-coming week, because it can't refer to a time in the past:

> I shall do that this week.

Using *next week* in a sentence like that introduces an ambiguity because *this week* obviously refers to the week starting today.

Comment: I think a duplicate or closely related question was asked and answered earlier here.

Comment: @Kris Yes, MetaEd found it. It's closely related but refers to a specific day (next Tuesday) rather than the whole week. This question on *this/next week* is arguably easier to interpret.

Comment: But if it's only Saturday, and your week (according to the ISO standard) ends on a Sunday, you might be promising to have it finished by tomorrow. So _this week_ might also introduce an ambiguity.