# Meaning of ‘following’ in the extract

Tags: meaning-in-context, ambiguity

Could anyone please clarify the meaning of ‘following‘ in the extract below. For me, it refers to not the Wednesday immediately after the Tuesday but rather the Wednesday of the next week - ‘the following Wednesday’. In the context of the book though it can only mean the next day and this is where the confusion for me arises.

> All the events related thus far took place on a Tuesday. On the
> morning of the following Wednesday, very early, between fix and six,
> Frau Rosenthal, accompanied by Trudel Baumann, left the Quangel
> apartment.

Comment: To me, (it is now Sunday) 'the coming' Thursday means the immediate Thursday (in four days' time). 'Next' Thursday means in eleven days' time. The 'following' Thursday means in eighteen days' time. But experience has taught me that not everyone understands this system, so it has to be clarified _each and every time it is stated_. There may - also - be differences between BrE (I'm a Brit) and AmE.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which day does "next Tuesday" refer to?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3841/which-day-does-next-tuesday-refer-to)

Comment: I don't think it's clear at all in your example. My first reaction was to assume that it meant the next day. I don't think there's a generally accepted rule, and it could be read either way. I understand why you feel confused.

Answer (score 0):

The following Wednesday is the day immediately after the Tuesday in question.

***[Following:](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese/following)***

> coming or happening after something else in order or time:

> - I’m busy on Thursday, but I’m free the following day.

(Cambridge Dictionary)