# The activity starts next week or starts from next week?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, ambiguity, time

Which one is correct, the activity **starts next week** or **starts from next week**? And why?

[Longman Dictionary](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/start) has this entry for 'start' in this sense:

> *intransitive, transitive*: to begin happening, or to make something begin happening

It also specifies the usage "starting (from) now/tomorrow/next week, etc," giving the example "You have two hours to complete the test, starting now."

[image: start from]

It's also been suggested to me that if I say *let's start (from) **next** Friday*, people sometimes could get confused regarding exactly which Friday I'm talking about.

So, it is better to use **the following** Friday instead of **next** Friday. Is this the case?

Here are the options:

1. Let's start next Friday
2. Let's start from next Friday
3. Let's start the following Friday
4. Let's start from the following Friday

Which is best?

Answer (score 2):

"Starting" is an activity that typically occurs at a single instant and does not extend over a duration of time. Therefore, the first option would be correct:

> the activity starts next week

Your other question has been dealt with already on this site, e.g.: [Which day does "next Tuesday" refer to?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3841/which-day-does-next-tuesday-refer-to)

Comment: Thanks for the link to my second question. But all the answers there didn't say would the adjective **following** reduce the ambiguity. Will it?

Comment: About my first question I googled it and found someone else asked here https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/start-next-week-or-start-from-next-week.3611668/  and an answer gave the same answer like yours: "In American English, at least, "start" refers to a specific point in time". But could British English  have a different story ?

Comment: Regarding "following", it depends. It's really a separate issue, though, so it should be asked in a separate question. Also, [ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/) would probably be a more appropriate place to ask that kind of question.

Comment: Regarding BrE, there's no difference as far as I know, but I can't say for certain.

Comment: Could you check my update to see why I had this question? It is because I check the longman dictionary.

Comment: Yes, if it's an activity that extends over a length of time you could say "starting from". If you want a specific answer, you should post a specific sentence. Otherwise I'm kind of guessing at what you mean.

Comment: "If you want a specific answer, you should post a specific sentence." actually what I posted in my question was what I want to know, i.e. should I use start or start from? After I saw your answer I googled it again and found the example in longman.

Comment: Longman puts _from_ in brackets, implying that it's optional. You can use either.

Comment: And if you want to avoid ambiguity give a date.

Comment: @Kate And there are plenty of examples of including ones from Southwark Council (https://moderngov.southwark.gov.uk ) and Science Direct (https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0094576599001599).